# Customizing java.text formatters for different Locales

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, locale

Building a java application that supports different Locales, but would like to customize the `DateFormat` display beyond what is available between `FULL`, `LONG`, `MEDIUM`, and `SHORT` DateFormat options.  Would like to do things like place a character between the date and time components of a `DateFormat.getDateTimeFormat()`, lowercase the AM/PM, etc, at least for english.

can think of 3 ways to do it:

1) if locale is english, use my custom format string on a `new SimpleDateFormat` object.

2) modify the default format strings for existing locales

3) create a new locale variant that specifies the format strings I want

Can't figure out how to do 2 or 3 (or if it's even possible), and would rather not do 1...  has anyone dealt with anything like this before?

also, seems like 2 or 3 would be necessary for lowercasing the AM/PM ?  (Specifiying the AmPmMarkers resource for the locale's dateformat settings)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a MessageFormat instead?

Use the pattern "{0,date,short} your text here {0,time,short}" to do what you want.

Comment: because sometimes it should be "{0,time,short} your text here {0,date,short}", depending on the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a Class just for this, it is the [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html) Class. [Back](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html) it with a properties file and you have all that you need plus more.

Even without the ResourceBundle Class you could use [properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) files to hold all the SimpleDateFormat formats.

```
Settings formats = new Settings();
Properties SDFFormats = formats.load(propertiesFile);

String SDFAmerica = SDFFormats.getProperty("FormatAmerica");
```

While the entry into the properties file might read

```
FormatAmerica = MMM-dd-yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing similar I've dealt with is the fact that "strftime" and "locale" say that Italian should use colons between the time fields, but Java puts full-stops between them.  So I've added the following code:

```
  // This is an incredibly ugly hack, but it's based on the fact that
  // Java for some reason decided that Italy uses "." between
  // hours.minutes.seconds, even though "locale" and strftime say
  // something different.
      hmsTimeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
      if (hmsTimeFormat instanceof SimpleDateFormat)
      {
        String str = ((SimpleDateFormat)hmsTimeFormat).toPattern();
        str = str.replace('.', ':');
        hmsTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(str);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most satisfying way to solve this that we've figured out is to load Strings am,pm,formatString from a locale-specific resource bundle, and then:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat)sdf.getDateTimeInstance(DateTime.SHORT,DateTime.SHORT, locale);
if (formatString != null) {
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
}
if (am!= null && pm != null) {
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = sdf.getDateFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setAmPmStrings(new String[]{am, pm});
    sdf.setDateFormatSymbols(symbols);
}
```

Paul: not sure there's a separator in the DateFormatSymbols, though...  so you probably need to keep the str.replace

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for your date formatting. It is has powerful yet elegant flexibility in its formatting. You'll probably find that its formatters make what you want to do extremely simple.

BTW: once you go Joda you'll never go back!