# Displaying AM and PM in lower case after date formatting

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

After formatting a datetime, the time displays AM or PM in upper case, but I want it in lower case like am or pm.

This is my code:

```
public class Timeis {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        long ts = 1022895271767L;
        String st = null;  
        st = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM d 'at' hh:mm a").format(ts);
        System.out.println("time is " + ts);  
    }
}
```

Comment: `st.toLowerCase()` will do it and there is no easier way.

Comment: The trouble is that, like month and day names, the AM/PM marker is locale-specific - it may not make sense in some languages to force everything to lower case (leaving aside the fact that some languages just use 24 hour clock for everything and don't really have terms for AM and PM at all).

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant`, `ZoneId` `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Unfortunately the standard formatting methods don't let you do that. Nor does Joda. I think you're going to have to process your formatted date by a simple post-format replace.

```
String str = oldstr.replace("AM", "am").replace("PM","pm");
```

You could use the `replaceAll()` method that uses regepxs, but I think the above is perhaps sufficient. I'm *not* doing a blanket `toLowerCase()` since that could screw up formatting if you change the format string in the future to contain (say) month names or similar.

EDIT: [James Jithin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13581910/2911458) looks a lot better, and the proper way to do this (as noted in the comments)

Comment: All answers are correct or near to correct. But ths Answer is simple and meet my criteria

Comment: [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13581910/1288725) posted by `James Jithin` is perfect approach to do it.

Comment: I prefer Brian Agnew's solution. It's the Agile approach. The least amount of code that could possibly work.

Comment: a variation `timeStr = timeStr.toLowerCase(Locale.UK);`

Comment: This answer is not good enough because some phones display AM/PM, others display a.m./p.m. James Jithin response handles that and is therefore better.

Comment: For my needs the ColdFusion equivalent of this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 103):

This works

```
public class Timeis {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        long ts = 1022895271767L;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM d 'at' hh:mm a");
        // CREATE DateFormatSymbols WITH ALL SYMBOLS FROM (DEFAULT) Locale
        DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
        // OVERRIDE SOME symbols WHILE RETAINING OTHERS
        symbols.setAmPmStrings(new String[] { "am", "pm" });
        sdf.setDateFormatSymbols(symbols);
        String st = sdf.format(ts);
        System.out.println("time is " + st);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrianAgnew, Not sure, you may try updating the property of the DateFormatSymbols instance received from http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#getDateFormatSymbols%28java.util.Locale%29

Comment: When specifying `Locale` in `SimpleDateFormate`, using `DateFormatSymbols` messes it up. You would probable have to specifically set all of the symbols and not just am/pm.

Comment: thanks working great,  provided in my case need to replace `" "` with `""`, e.g **hh:mm a** to **hh:mma**

Answer (score 9):

**If you don't want to do string substitution, and are using Java 8** `javax.time`:

```
Map<Long, String> ampm = new HashMap<>();
ampm.put(0l, "am");
ampm.put(1l, "pm");

DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("E M/d h:mm")
        .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, ampm)
        .toFormatter()
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

It's necessary to manually build a `DateTimeFormatter` (specifying individual pieces), as there is no pattern symbol for lowercase am/pm. You can use `appendPattern` before and after.

I believe there is no way to substitute the default am/pm symbols, making this is the only way short of doing the string replace on the final string.

Answer (score 7):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
formattedDate = formattedDate.replace("a.m.", "AM").replace("p.m.","PM");

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Simple to the Core. Sure shot procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("time is " + ts.toLowerCase());
```

Although you may be able to create a custom format as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223325/customizing-java-text-formatters-for-different-locales) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Unfortunately out of the [box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the AM and PM do not seem to be customisable in the standard SimpleDateFormat class

Comment: This would make the ntire string to lower case, i guess OP just need lower case am/pm, otherwise, its a good solution :)

Comment: Yes i tried it you are correct @Brian Agnew's answer is very correct

Answer (score 3):

```
    String today = now.format(new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("MM/dd/yyyy ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY)
            .appendLiteral(" (PST)")
            .toFormatter(Locale.UK));
```

// output => 06/18/2019 am (PST)

Locale.UK => am or pm;
Locale.US => AM or PM; try different locale for your needs (defaul, etc.)

Comment: Setting the Locale did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

James's answer is great if you want different style other than default am, pm. But I'm afraid you need mapping between Locale and Locale specific AM/PM set to adopting the override. Now you simply use java built-in java.util.Formatter class. So an easy example looks like this:

```
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.UK, "%1$tl%1$tp", LocalTime.now()));
```

It gives:

```
9pm
```

To note that if you want upper case, just replace "%1$**t**p" with "%1$**T**p". You can find more details at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt.

Answer (score 2):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d 'at' hh:mm a", new Locale("en", "IN"));
```

change to a locale that uses am/pm instead of AM/PM.

Answer (score 0):

just add `toLowarCase()` like this

```
public class Timeis {
public static void main(String s[]) {
      long ts = 1022895271767L;
      String st = null;  
      st = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM d 'at' hh:mm a").format(ts).toLowerCase();
      System.out.println("time is " + ts);  
}
}
```

and `toUpperCase()` if you want upper case

Comment: This will lowercase the month also.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we perform in android studio's java code pass unix timestamp as parameter

```
private String convertTimeToTimeStamp(Long timeStamp){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa", Locale.getDefault());
            return sdf.format(timeStamp);
        }
```

function returns time of format 09:30 PM

Answer (score 0):

## dateString.toLowerCase();

String timeString=
new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM d 'at' hh:mma")
.format(timestaamp)
.toLowerCase();

System.out.println("time is " + tstimeString);