# Change date and time format

Tags: java

I have a string with the following time and date format: "13-Dec-2013 20:24:50" how can I change it to this format "Fri, Dec 13, 2013 8:24 pm"? I'm using Java as my language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `DateFormat` that fits yours, parse your input string, create another `DateFormat` which fits your desired output format, format your date.

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date d = inputFormat.parse("13-Dec-2013 20:24:50");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MMM-yyyy");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(d));
```

I already wrote a `DateFormat` which fits your input string. Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you should be able to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: Just wondering - is there an _easy & nice_ way to get "pm" instead of "PM", which yields from `SimpleDateFormat` formatting? It would be nice if one could change the AM/PM strings in an existing (derived) DateFormat object.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581608/displaying-am-and-pm-in-small-letter-after-date-formatting

Comment: I changed the format to this: DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); and it works perfectly now