# Unparseable date in Groovy

Tags: groovy

how to parse date format like `"10/07/2018 10:07 pm"` in Groovy.

Below format we are used

```
Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:SS","10/07/2018 10:07 pm")
```

is it correct

Answer (score 1):

No, it should be

```
Date d = Date.parse("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa","10/07/2018 10:07 pm")
```

​
Or if you're running on top of Java 8, you can use the much nicer

```
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.parse(
    "10/07/2018 10:07 pm",
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Java 8 types instead of `java.util.Date`. Sadly, there's not a straightforward way to accommodate the lower case "pm" with `DateTimeFormatter`. The cheap way is to upper-case the String:

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse('10/07/2018 10:07 pm'.toUpperCase(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a')
```

The more "proper" way, as described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581608/displaying-am-and-pm-in-small-letter-after-date-formatting), is:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.*
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField

DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm ')
        .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, [(0L):'am',(1L):'pm'])
        .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime.parse('10/07/2018 10:07 pm', dtf)
```

Answer (score 0):

The format should be dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:SS a

```
Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:SS a","10-07-2018 10:07:00 am")
Date.parse("dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM a","10/07/2018 10:07 pm")
```

​Please check the results here:
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5203535180333056